# Z-index in winapi

Tags: winapi

I need the ability to set the window not only z-type (always top/always bottom/etc.), but also z-index (0..+inf.).

Windows with smaller z-index values ​​should be lower than windows with greater.
I know about SetWindowPos and it`s parameter hWndInsertAfter, using it I can achieve what I want, but this way seems too complicated.
Is there better solution ?

Comment: This seems like an X-Y problem.  Can you describe the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

The windowing subsystem maintains the [Z-Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#zorder), implemented as a list:

> The system maintains the z-order in a single list.

You can move windows in this list (by calling [SetWindowPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) for example), passing the previous window as an index, or `HWND_TOP` to move a window to the front. There is no API that uses an ordinal as the index.

If you need to insert a window ahead of another window, call [`GetNextWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633509.aspx)`(GW_HWNDPREV)` first to be passed as the *hWndInsertAfter*. If there is no window ahead in the z-order, `GetNextWindow` returns `NULL`, which conveniently maps to `HWND_TOP`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @IInspectable.
I indicated in the question that I know about SetWindowPos.
I want (for example) that after moving the window and losing focus to it, its z-order remains the same as before the move.
Desired behavior:
I set the z-index. The user through the gui moves the window. When it finishes its z-index window remains as before the motion.
If I set z-index using SetWindowPos it will not work as described above.

Comment: @MaximFedorov: If you need to permanently retain the relative z-order between a subset of windows, set the owner. Owned windows are always in front of their respective owners. Bringing the owner to the front automatically moves the owned windows to the front as well. But maybe I didn't understand your question. It would help if you abstracted your problem down to its core instead of describing your use-case by example.